# Get the newest and oldest date from a list - Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, sorting

I have an array of Ruby Date objects. How can I find the newest datetime and the oldest datetime?

Comment: The question should be changed to how to find the newest and oldest datetime, as most recent would infer that the returned date is always in the past, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
date_array.min # => Oldest
date_array.max # => Most recent
```

Comment: date_array.max does not give the "Most recent" date, it gives the newest date. Most recent would infer that it would give the most recent date in the past. For instance Date.today would be the most recent date, however the date set the farthest in the future would be returned with date_array.max

Answer (score 3):

```
oldest, newest =  date_array.minmax
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a comparison operator:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000673

Sort it.

Comment: Sorting is lin * log, simply min/max is pure linear.

Comment: Link is broken.